# Add randomly selected column to result

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I'd like to know if there is a more optimal query to get what I want from the database.

My database schema is as follows :

Table1:
(NUM_T1C1;ID_T1C2)

Table2:
(ID_T2C1;RES_T2C2)

First, I want to get a random row defined as:

```
SELECT NUM_T1C1, ID_T2C1
FROM (
    SELECT T1.NUM_T1C1, T2.ID_T2C1, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
    FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
    WHERE T1.NUM_T1C1 IS NOT NULL
    AND T2.RES_T2C2 IS NOT NULL
    AND T1.ID_T1C2 = T2.ID_T2C1
    ORDER BY 3
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

I will call this query: QUERY1.

My question is as follows, I want to get a row as `(random NUM_T1C1 != QUERY1.NUM_T1C1; ID_T2C1 == QUERY1.ID_T2C1)`, so I have tried:

```
SELECT NUM_T1C1, ID_T2C1
FROM (
    SELECT R2.NUM_T1C1, R1.ID_T2C1, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
    FROM (
        SELECT NUM_T1C1, ID_T2C1
        FROM (
            SELECT T1.NUM_T1C1, T2.ID_T2C1, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
            FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
            WHERE T1.NUM_T1C1 IS NOT NULL
            AND T2.RES_T2C2 IS NOT NULL
            AND T1.ID_T1C2 = T2.ID_T2C1
            ORDER BY 3
        ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
    ) R1, TABLE1 R2
    WHERE R2.NUM_T1C1 <> R1.NUM_T1C1
    ORDER BY 3
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

It's working, but I think this is not the optimal way to do so.
Is there a better way to get the expected result?

---

EDIT:

I found another way to get those random rows but i still don't know if it's optimal:

```
SELECT NUM_T1C1, ID_T2C1
FROM (
    SELECT R1.NUM_T1C1, R2.ID_T2C1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT T1.NUM_T1C1, T2.ID_T2C1, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
        FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
        WHERE T1.NUM_T1C1 IS NOT NULL
        AND T2.T2C2 IS NULL
        AND T1.ID_T1C2 = T2.ID_T2C1
        ORDER BY 3
    ) R1,
    (
        SELECT T2.ID_T2C1, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
        FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
        WHERE T1.NUM_T1C1 IS NOT NULL
        AND T2.T2C2 IS NOT NULL
        AND T1.ID_T1C2 = T2.ID_T2C1
        ORDER BY 2
    ) R2
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Here is an example :

```
        Table1                  Table2
+----------+---------+  +---------+----------+
| NUM_T1C1 | ID_T1C2 |  | ID_T2C1 | RES_T2C2 |
+----------+---------+  +---------+----------+
| 23       | 5       |  | 9       | NULL     |
| 521      | 4       |  | 4       | DG_513   |
| 71       | 7       |  | 7       | FN_731   |
| 97       | 9       |  | 5       | NULL     |
+----------+---------+  +---------+----------+
```

Result would be one of those (select one randomly) :

```
+----------+---------+
| NUM_T1C1 | ID_T2C1 |
+----------+---------+
| 23       | 4       |
| 23       | 7       |
| 97       | 4       |
| 97       | 7       |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Can you add a text description of what your code snippet is trying to achieve as trying to interpret your requirements by reading the code is prone to misinterpretation.

Comment: Hi @mt0,
I'd like to select a random row (NUM_T1C1) from Table1 and a random row (ID_T2C1) that has a response (RES_T2C2 IS NOT NULL) from Table2 and those two rows should not be linked (Table1.ID_T1C1 != Table2.ID_T2C1).
It must be emphasised that NUM_T1C1 should not have a response.

Comment: @Z.Walid . . . Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited my post and added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way with only a single (cross) join:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3701fc/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( NUM_T1C1, ID_T1C2 ) AS
SELECT  23, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 521, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  71, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  97, 9 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 ( ID_T2C1, RES_T2C2 ) As
SELECT 9, NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'DG_513' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'FN_731' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL     FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT NUM_T1C1, ID_T2C1
FROM   (
  SELECT NUM_T1C1,
         ID_T2C1,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN T1.ID_T1C2 = T2.ID_T2C1 THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY T1.NUM_T1C1 ) AS num_matches
  FROM   Table1 T1
         CROSS JOIN
         (
           SELECT *
           FROM   Table2
           WHERE  RES_T2C2 IS NOT NULL
         ) T2
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
)
WHERE  num_matches = 0
--AND    ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3701fc/3/0)**:

```
| NUM_T1C1 | ID_T2C1 |
|----------|---------|
|       23 |       7 |
|       97 |       4 |
|       97 |       7 |
|       23 |       4 |
```

Comment: That worked! thank you. I'll try to analyze it later cause it looks a little bit complex for me.